# Javascript Date.toLocaleString() ignored in Apigee API Platform

Tags: javascript, apigee

I'm developing a API Proxy in Apigee API Platform. I'm using a Javascript script to convert a Date to a User-Friendly representation.
So I have this code:

```
var endDate = new Date(2014, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
var options = {
  localeMatcher: 'best fit',
  weekDay: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  timezone: 'America/El_Salvador',
  timeZoneName: 'short'
};
var friendly_endDate = endDate.toLocaleDateString('es-SV', options);
```

And I always end up with a en-US formatted date like the following:

```
February 1, 2014 12:00:00 UTC
```

Timezone, options and locale is ignored. is this normal? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Rhino (1.7R4) was [released](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Downloads_archive) on 6/18/2012. According to the [Mozilla docs on Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), the locales and options arguments were added with the [ECMAScript Internalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/), which looks like it came out in December 2012.

I think your best bet is to find a JavaScript library that can be included for your policy, and use that. See the [Apigee JavaScript policy documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/customize-api-using-javascript) for instructions on including JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I use [moment JS](http://momentjs.com/) libray. Very nicely design simple library for JS base Date manipulations. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

We also have a working sample that shows you how to work with JavaScript libraries as includes in an API proxy:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/base64encoder